# @ notation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server, can someone help me what is the significance of `@` notation followed by name of variable? Like `@OrderId` ?

Comment: What has your researched turned up so far?

Answer (score 0):

All SQL Server variables are prefixed with `@`.

> @local_variable
>   Is the name of a variable. Variable names must begin
>   with an at (@) sign. Local variable names must comply with the rules
>   for identifiers.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx